# How to Add Xcode Bot Integration Number Into Build Script

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, bots, build-script

I'm creating an iPad application with a Settings.bundle file. I'm writing build scripts to display the application version number and the xcode bot integration number (not the bundle build number). I've searched the web and couldn't find any solution. Here's what I got yet:

```
-- Add the app version number
cd $PROJECT_DIR
cd "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME.app"

RELEASE_VERSION=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" Info.plist)
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :PreferenceSpecifiers:1:DefaultValue $RELEASE_VERSION" Settings.bundle/Root.plist

-- Add the build version number
BUILD_NUMBER=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" Info.plist)
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :PreferenceSpecifiers:2:DefaultValue $BUILD_NUMBER" Settings.bundle/Root.plist
```

In the build version number, I would like to replace the CFBundleVersion with the xcode bot Integration number.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I implemented this using a **Shell Script Build Phase** in my **Xcode** project. In my case, I used the integration number to set the *internal version* of my built product. My script looks like this:

```
if [ "the$XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER" == "the" ]; then
    echo "Not an integration build…"
    xcrun agvtool new-version "10.13"
else
    echo "Setting integration build number: $XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER"
    xcrun agvtool new-version "$XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER"
fi
```

Note that `XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER` exists by default in the **Xcode Server** build environment. If you want to simulate an integration build (for the purposes of this script), you can simply add it to your build settings as a custom variable.

Answer (score 7):

You actually don't even need agvtool to set the build number to the Xcode bot integration number. Simply set the Build number to ${XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER} in your project settings.

Comment: Note this can result in an error if running unit tests from a non Xcode server machine. "Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion".

Answer (score 5):

I added (+) a **Run Script** to my targets **Build Phase** just prior to **Compile Sources** step. This one line script works for me to set the integration number as the build number. Thanks Kaelin, I just wanted to simplify things a little bit.

```
[ -z "$XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER" ] && echo "Build #0" || xcrun agvtool new-version ${XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am setting this up with Xcode 10.1 on os 10.14.2, and found a couple of modifications were needed to make Kaelin's answer work. Here is my complete script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $XCS_PRIMARY_REPO_DIR
xcrun agvtool new-version -all "$XCS_BOT_NAME - Int. $XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER"
```

The mods are to change the directory (cd) to where the project lives when built. The other one is to add -all to the xcrun arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled over the same issue recently. 
There is a very pragmatic but ugly way of getting information about the latest integration number of Xcode Bots runs:

```
sudo grep -r "integration =" /Library/Server/Xcode/Logs/xcsbuildd.log | tail -1 | cut -d'=' -f 2| cut -d';' -f 1 |tr -d '\040\011\012\015'
```

I also created a stackoverflow question in order to find a more integrated and less hacky way of accomplishing this goal:
[Register for messages from collabd like XCSBuildService to receive Xcode Bots integration number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875979/register-for-messages-from-collabd-like-xcsbuildservice-to-receive-xcode-bots-in)

But maybe the way parsing the xcsbuildd.log as described above is sufficient for your purposes.