# Register for messages from collabd like XCSBuildService to receive Xcode Bots integration number

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration, bots

During an Xcode Bots build each run gets an **integration number** assigned. This number does not show in the build logs but would be convenient to create http links back to the individual Xcode Bots build in an CI environment or enterprise app store.

In the **/Library/Server/Xcode/Logs/xcsbuildd.log** I found that **XCSBuildService** gets a message/event from **collabd** with a structure that contains the integration number.

***Is there a way to register to the same event in an own (OSX) program and receive this message/event?***

---

The only *ugly* way I found so far to get the Xcode Bots integration number was by parsing the xcsbuildd.log file with the drawback that I can't be sure that the latest integration number corresponds with my current build when several builds are executing in parallel. 
This log file is also located in an read protected folder/file so that I have to either change the permissions (ugh!) or use sudo (I don't really want to do that)!?

Example:

```
sudo grep -r "integration =" /Library/Server/Xcode/Logs/xcsbuildd.log | tail -1 | cut -d'=' -f 2| cut -d';' -f 1 |tr -d '\040\011\012\015'
```

Gives me the latest integration number stripped from whitespace ...

**Edit:**
Just found out that if you actually include the following script in your scheme as Build-post-action it will create a file *(e.g. /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/22016b1e-2f91-4757-b3b8-322233e87587/source/integration_number.txt)* with the integration number without requiring sudo. Xcode Bots seems to serialize the different builds so that they are not executed in parallel and so the created integration number in the file could be used.

```
grep -r "integration =" /Library/Server/Xcode/Logs/xcsbuildd.log | tail -1 | cut -d'=' -f 2| cut -d';' -f 1 |tr -d '\040\011\012\015' >  ${PROJECT_DIR}/integration_number.txt
```

Comment: You can clean this up a bit by using sed: `sed -E 's|.* ([0-9]+);|\1|'` will replace the cuts and tr, so the solution becomes `grep -r "integration =" /Library/Server/Xcode/Logs/xcsbuildd.log | tail -1 | sed -E 's|.* ([0-9]+);|\1|' > ${PROJECT_DIR}/integration_number.txt`

Answer (score 0):

For specifically the case of getting the integration build number, I've added a simple answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988378/how-to-add-xcode-bot-integration-number-into-build-script).

To repeat myself (and keep this from being down voted as a 1-line answer):

---

I implemented this using a **Shell Script Build Phase** in my **Xcode** project. In my case, I used the integration number to set the *internal version* of my built product. My script looks like this:

```
if [ "the$XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER" == "the" ]; then
    echo "Not an integration build…"
    xcrun agvtool new-version "10.13"
else
    echo "Setting integration build number: $XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER"
    xcrun agvtool new-version "$XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER"
fi
```

Note that `XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER` exists by default in the **Xcode Server** build environment. If you want to simulate an integration build (for the purposes of this script), you can simply add it to your build settings as a custom variable.